# Syscall Sequence used when mounting and changing files in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, kernel-module

I am working on a Linux project.
I want to know which syscalls are called in what sequence when we mount a filesystem using mount command and also which syscalls are called when we read,write,delete files in that file system.

Is there any good resource for this ?

Thanks

Comment: [mount(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) is a syscall.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `strace` ?

For example like this:

```
> sudo strace mount /tmp/loop_image mount_point/ -o loop

execve("/bin/mount", ["mount", "/tmp/loop_image", "mount_point/", "-o", "loop"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x195c000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7faeb36c6000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=136922, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 136922, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faeb36a4000
... etc ...
```

Just few system calls here, I skipped the rest, but I think this way you can see what is called when mount is executed.

You can use `strace` also for your own programs, so you can create simple programs with the use cases you need, and see what is being called on the kernel side.